# Assignment to data.frame causes an unwanted type change in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I generate some data like so:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100))
dat[sample(nrow(dat), 5), 3] <- NaN
dat[sample(nrow(dat), 5), 3] <- Inf
```

Now, some of the z-values are `Inf` or `NaN`.

The first 10 rows of the results from

```
cut(dat$z[is.finite(dat$z)],6)[1:10]
```

are

```
 [1] (0.286,1.17]   (0.286,1.17]   (0.286,1.17]   (0.286,1.17]   (0.286,1.17]  
 [6] (0.286,1.17]   (-1.48,-0.599] (-1.48,-0.599] (-0.599,0.286] (0.286,1.17]  
6 Levels: (-2.37,-1.48] (-1.48,-0.599] (-0.599,0.286] ... (2.06,2.94]
```

but if I try to make the following assignment

```
dat$col[is.finite(dat$z)] <- cut(dat$z[is.finite(dat$z)],6)
```

I get integers instead of the labels:

```
> dat$col[1:10]
 [1]  4  4  4  4  4  4  2  2 NA  3
```

How do I assign the factor labels correctly just to the subset of rows?

Thanks!
Uri

Comment: That's pretty normal. You have a numeric column there, of which you change some values with the result of cut. As that's a factor (which is a numeric with labels in essence), you'll just paste the numeric values and not the labels. So R is not doing an unwanted type change. You expect a type change where R refuses, that's your problem. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat[is.finite(dat$z),"col"] <- cut(dat$z[is.finite(dat$z)],6)
```

Should work.  I don't know why assigning via `$` doesn't, though.

Comment: The `$<-` function is different than the `[<-` function, and the ?Extract page informs us that there is no data.frame method for `$<-`.

Comment: @DWin But there is a `$<-.data.frame` method in base. The `?Extract` page says there is only `$` methods (and thus presumably `$<-` methods) for recursive data types, and `data.frame` is a `list` which is a recursive type.

Comment: I see that you are right that such a method exists (although it is different than the `[<-.data.frame` function. I was reading the sentence : "Note that there is no data.frame method for $, so x$name uses the default method which treats x as a list." and made erroneous conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure that my answer is what you want, but if you want the labels instead of the integers representing the factor try `as.character`:

```
dat$col[is.finite(dat$z)] <- as.character(cut(dat$z[is.finite(dat$z)],6))
```

if you want it to be a factor instead of a character vector, wrap this into a call to factor:

```
dat$col[is.finite(dat$z)] <- factor(as.character(cut(dat$z[is.finite(dat$z)],6)))
```